Why gcc can put _start at 0x1040 while custom assembly code and linker script can not?
I was leaning linker script and wrote assembly code as below:
#hello.s
.data                 
    msg : .string "Hello, world!\n"
    len = . - msg

.text
.global _start
         
_start:      
    movl $len, %edx
    movl $msg, %ecx
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $4, %eax    # sys_write
    int  $0x80
        
    movl $0,%ebx
    movl $1,%eax     # sys_exit
    int  $0x80


and linker script as below:
/* hello.ld */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS 
{   
    . = 0x10000;

    .text :
    {
        *(.text);
    }

    .data :
    {
        *(.data);
    }

    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss);
    }

}


as -o hello.o hello.s 
ld -T hello.ld -o hello hello.o 
./hello

hello can be executed normally when setting .=0x10000. But when I set .=0x1040, I got Segmentation fault. There is an answer in here that explains why custom code can not be put before address 0x10000.
However, When I used readelf -h to get informations of an executable file(such as a.out) which was generated by gcc, the entry point address is 0x1040. Using objdump -d to disassemble such file can also find the definition of _start at 0x1040. But gdb can not insert a breakpoint in that position by b *1040. When using b _start and run in gdb, there is an another _start in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.

here's the definition in 0x1040:

0000000000001040 <_start>:
  1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  1044:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  1046:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  1049:       5e                      pop    %rsi
  104a:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  104d:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  1051:       50                      push   %rax
  1052:       54                      push   %rsp
  1053:       45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
  1056:       31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
  1058:       48 8d 3d ca 00 00 00    lea    0xca(%rip),%rdi        # 1129 <main>
  105f:       ff 15 73 2f 00 00       call   *0x2f73(%rip)        # 3fd8 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34>
  1065:       f4                      hlt    
  1066:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  106d:       00 00 00 

The question is:

Why gcc can put _start in address 0x1040?
Will the code at 0x1040 be executed?
which _start is the true one?

I have searched in google but only found why custom code can not be put before 0x10000 in here.
